# Is there an event which fires after user is authenticated?

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-asax

Is there any event in global.asax that is fired just once after the user is authenticated or authorized? Session start fires whenever user enter in application no matter he's authorized or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this event in global.asax page ,for check current user if logedin and store the user details in `httpconext.current.user` .

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.User != null)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity is FormsIdentity)
            {
                FormsIdentity id =
                    (FormsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
                FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = id.Ticket;

                // Get the stored user-data, in this case, our roles
                string userData = ticket.UserData;
                string[] roles = userData.Split(',');
                HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(id, roles);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `AuthenticateRequest` fires on every request allowing you to prepare the HttpContext for the execution of the request.